# Android SDK - Command line tool in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, sdk

I have noticed that our Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2019 using Android SDK, which is using log4j internally. It’s under command line tool located at –
\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\2.1\lib\external\lint-psi\intellij-core\intellij-core-all.jar

Is it not impacted by this vulnerability? Could you please advise.